# grafana convert ps_cputime into percentage

Tags: sql, grafana, influxdb, cpu-time

I trying to plot `memcached` data in influxdb + grafana and i found `ps_cputime` is in `microsecond`.

How do i convert it in human readable format so easy to understand.

influxdb:

```
> select * from memcached_syst limit 10;
name: memcached_syst
time                host                                         type       value
----                ----                                         ----       -----
1549595956627272659 ostack-infra-01_memcached_container-167ecaa7 ps_cputime 15853819249
1549596016550515653 ostack-infra-01_memcached_container-167ecaa7 ps_cputime 15853923573
1549596076550356985 ostack-infra-01_memcached_container-167ecaa7 ps_cputime 15854047878
1549596136550415911 ostack-infra-01_memcached_container-167ecaa7 ps_cputime 15854165969
1549596196550481720 ostack-infra-01_memcached_container-167ecaa7 ps_cputime 15854288341
1549596256550522792 ostack-infra-01_memcached_container-167ecaa7 ps_cputime 15854387422
```

Grafana query:

```
SELECT mean("value") FROM "memcached_syst"  WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/ AND "type"='ps_cputime' ) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) fill(null)
```

what i can do here to make it in parcent?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NON_NEGATIVE_DERIVATIVE`, result will be in percentage:

```
SELECT NON_NEGATIVE_DERIVATIVE("value", 1s) / 1000
FROM "memcached_syst"
WHERE ("host" =~ /^$host$/ AND "type"='ps_cputime' ) AND $timeFilter
GROUP BY time($interval) fill(null)
```

This query may need some tuning, for example normalization by the number of cores.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert microseconds to hours and display the result.
Formula to convert to hours - microseconds / 3600000000

```
  Select (column_name/3600000000)      as time_in_hrs from table_name;
```